# all() matlab function opencv

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

Is there an equivalent OpenCV function for `all()` function from MATLAB?

```
if all(bwImg(:)) || all(~bwImg(:))
....
end
```

This is the code I'm trying to implement. Of course I can iterate over all of the values and check if they are 1 or zero.

Comment: if your matrix is binary, you can check its `sum`

Comment: @Shai thanks great idea. and yes it is binary

Comment: @Shai please look at my answer, is this what you meant?

Comment: Try: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`countNonZero`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) is your best bet.  Something like:

```
cv::Mat bwImg;
// get yoru binary image

int nz = cv::countNonZero(bwImg);
if (nz==bwImg.size().area() || nz==0)
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Shai [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003767/all-matlab-function-opencv#comment44396194_28003767)...

```
double sum = cv::sum(dst)[0];
if(sum == dst.rows * dst.cols||sum == 0 )
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: First, binary image created by OpenCV is an image with values 0 and 255, not 0 and 1, i.e. sum=255*rows*cols. Second, checking if non-integer value is equal to something is a dangerous thing (even if it works usually). In any case, Micka's advice is the best in your situation.

Comment: @MichaelBurdinov I have created the image. it is only 1 and 0